# Using Ruby on Rails 5, how do I define a URL route with unknown/:folder/:sub-folder depth and save/recall it from Postgresql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, url-routing

In my application, users will be able to create categories and I would like the "breadcrumb" to be visible in the URL, i.e.

```
www.domain.com/user/:user_id/folder/:top-folder-slug/:sub-folder-slug/:sub-sub-folder-slug
```

I do not intend to have a limit on the levels of sub-folders a user can create so I'm needing to know if it is possible to define a route in Rails that will accept an unknown amount of folder parameters and, idealy, make them available to me with a sequential number appended to the params (params[folder1], params[folder2]). Is this possible?

This presents another challange as to how to store the entire breadcrumb in the database, as I can't just dynamically add "folder 1", "folder 2", etc, columns as needed and I'm not sure the performance/scalability of storing it all in jsonb column. Perhaps it would be necessary to only display parent-folder and current-folder in the URL and database, (i.e. below) and just query base on those?

```
www.domain.com/user/:id/folder/.../parent-folder/current-folder
```

Any insight on how to get to where I'm after would be appreciated.

Comment: Not very sure but Dynamic Rails Routing might help you. Follow this [link](http://codeconnoisseur.org/ramblings/creating-dynamic-routes-at-runtime-in-rails-4)